# Why is int implicitly cast to float rather than double when invoking constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I wrote this test code

```
public class ConstructorTestApplication {

    private static String result;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConstructorTest test1 = new ConstructorTest(0);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static class ConstructorTest {

        public ConstructorTest(double param){
            result = "double constructor called!";
        }
        public ConstructorTest(float param) {
            result = "float constructor called!";
        }


    }
}
```

The result was

```
float constructor called!
```

Why was the float constructor called rather than the double constructor? Is this part of the dynamic method lookup?

Comment: Were you expecting that it was cast to double? If so, why?

Comment: I was not expecting one way or the other. The question came up in class and I wrote the test to see but I don't know why the float takes precedence over the double.

Comment: There is no dynamic method lookup here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ConstructorTest(float param)` is the most specific method out of the two constructors, since a method with a `double` argument can accept any `float` value, but the opposite is not true.

[JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> 15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method
>
> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that **the most specific method is chosen**.
>
> The informal intuition is that **one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error**.

Answer (score 3):

I present [JLS 5.3. Method Invocation Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) and [5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
> primitive conversions:
>
> byte to short, int, long, float, or double
>
> short to int, long, float, or double
>
> char to int, long, float, or double
>
> int to long, float, or double
>
> long to float or double
>
> float to double

Essentially floats are put in priority over doubles in method overloading when casting is done.